# optimize ajax call

Tags: jquery, ajax, optimization

I need to grab several items from other page right now my jquerycalls looks like this

```
$('.slide1 .pic').load('url div.zoomPad');
$('.slide1 .title').load('url .pname');
$('.slide1 .other').load('url .anotherdiv');
```

.. and so on.. is there a way to make just 1 call and grab all elements? and then place them where I want?

im going to do 7 calls in 7 different pages so I dont think it would be a good Idea to make the calls like that .. there should be a cleaner way.. do you know any?

Comment: If you can adjust the server to return `json` you can do this with easy. see my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `.ajax` instead of `.load` and handle the response yourself in the `success` handler.

```
$.ajax({...
    success: function(data){
        $('.slide1 .pic').html($(data).find('div.zoomPad'));
        // etc.
    ...
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes there is the `ajax` function for lower level:

```
$.ajax({
  url: "test.html",
  dataType: json 
  success: function(data){
    $('.first').val(data.first);
    $('.second').val(data.second);
    //...
    $('.n').val(data.n); // Sorry for the n part, 
                        // I have a test in Linear algebra soon...
  }
});
```

Make sure the server returns the data as `json` format, and you ready to go with easiest way.

[docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

Comment: Based on `data.first` etc., you are assuming that the response is JSON correct?

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
$('<div/>').load('url', function() {
    $('.slide1 .pic').html($(this).find('div.zoomPad'));
    $('.slide1 .title').html($(this).find('.pname'));
    $('.slide1 .other').html($(this).find('.anotherdiv'));
});
```

Basically, we do one Ajax call and store the response in a jQuery object. Then we can use `.find()` to parse the response to get what we want.

Comment: Good catch. It uses the complete callback function now.